Homotopy equivalence between certain loop spaces
I've been reading some papers carefully, with their proofs (Notations are given at the end).
The following comes from "Braids, mapping class groups and categorical delooping" by Song & Tillmann.
The group completion of $\coprod_{k \geq 0} BB_{k}$ is given by
$\mathcal{G}(\coprod_{k \geq 0} BB_{k}) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \times BB_{\infty}^{+} \simeq \Omega^{2}S^{2}$.
So,
$BB_{\infty}^{+} \simeq \Omega_0^{2} S^{2}$, where the subscript 0 indicates that only the 0-component is considered.
Now, the following seems to be a well-known result, but I am not able to see how :
$\Omega_0^{2} S^{2} \simeq \Omega^2S^{3}$.
Notations :
Let $B_n$ denote the braid group with $n$ strands, and let $B_{\infty}$ be its direct limit.
For a CW complex $X$, let $\Omega X$ be its loop space, $X^{+}$ its plus construction, and $S^n$ the $n$-sphere.
Given a (discrete) group $G$, we write $BG$ for its classifying space, and $\mathcal{G}$ for its group completion, i.e. $\mathcal{G} = \Omega B$.

For a simply-connected space $X$, you have $\Omega_0X = \Omega X$. So you can reduce the problem to showing $\Omega_0^2S^2 \simeq \Omega_0^2S^3$. I guess you mean homotopy equivalence here?

I think I'd want to actually write down the specific map, for instance looping the Hopf fibration $S^3 \to S^2$, to get $\Omega_0^2S^3 \to \Omega_0^2S^2$. But then this is a map of pointed connected spaces that induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups, and you should be able to use Whitehead's theorem to then get that this is a homotopy equivalence.

I have a similar question. How is the group completion of the disjoint union and $\mathbb{Z} \times BB_{\infty}^{+}$ homotopy equivalent?

@David Roberts, thank you so much! I can't believe I missed this part, I immediately got it when you said Hopf fibration :).

@May sounds like a good separate question ;-)

Okay, I have posted the question here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469350/group-completion-of-a-monoid-braid-groups

The point is that $S^3$ is the universal $2$-connected cover of $S^2$, via the Hopf fibration $S^3 \to S^2 \to K(\mathbb Z, 2)$.  As suggested by David Roberts, this map induces an isomorphism on $\pi_i$ for $i \geq 3$ (as you can see from the long exact sequence in homotopy).   So on double loop spaces, it induces an isomorphism on $\pi_i$ for $i \geq 1$,  hence an  equivalence when restricted to the zeroth connected component.

I got it immediately when David Roberts mentioned Hopf fibrations. Can't believe I missed this step! Thanks :)
